# LESSC in node.js: can't set initial PATH

Tags: node.js, less

I just intalled node.js via .msi installer.

Then, following [official documentation](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage), I installed **LESS** compiler.

Now, I would like to compile a `.less` file into corresponding `.css` one, but I can't.

I ran the following command from CMD, because I thought that should be necessary to set initial path in which it looked for `.less` file to be compile:

```
lessc --include-path=D:/projects/foo-website/docroot/less
```

But result is the following:

```
lessc: no input files
```

Obviously, files are inside that folder.

Please, I found very difficult to find a step-by-step guide to use node.js to compile LESS. Can you provide me detailed informations? Thanks

Comment: What would you expect to get with that command? Get all the less files in that directory to be compiled? No, this won't work that way. `lessc` compiles `file` not `files` (in a directory or so). Hence you need to specify what file you want it to compile. (And `--include-path` option is just "to configure a list of paths which less will use to find *imports* in").

Comment: @seven-phases-max: my problem is easier than expected. I simply would like to compile "`D:/projects/foo-website/docroot/less/style.less`" in "`D:/projects/foo-website/docroot/css/style.css`". My `.less` already includes `@import` clauses to others `.less` files.

Comment: So what you need is just `lessc D:/projects/foo-website/docroot/less/style.less`. (also depending on what you're doing in general it might be more wise to `cd` into that dir first and then just `lessc style.less` there).

Comment: Well, `lessc D:/projects/foo-website/docroot/less/style.less D:/projects/foo-website/docroot/css/style.css` right? It runs. Otherwise, writing only first part seems to simply print file content, or in other words, redirect processed code only on screen.

Comment: yes, with no output file specified the result outputs to the console itself.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have to solve problem to automate conversion. I know that this could be achieved with Grunt, but maybe it's exagerated for my needs. I found also [this link](https://github.com/jonycheung/Dead-Simple-LESS-Watch-Compiler) maybe could the solution